# How to locally run Heroku app one-off

Tags: heroku

I am writing an app that runs one-off on Heroku. So my Procfile is empty, I run on Heroku using

```
heroku run node index.js
```

For development purposes, I want to run it locally, and it must read the .env file automatically. But

```
Heroku local
```

attempts to read Procfile and then do nothing.

How can I run my app locally with heroku cli and make it read .env automatically?

Answer (score 1):

use `Heroku local:run node index.js`